# html input capture="camera" does not work, it opens a gallery on phonegap app (android)

Tags: android, html, cordova, camera, capture

I'm creating an app with PhoneGap, the HTML/CSS/js is automatically generated by our own (PHP) framework.
We do this because we want to have our website code the same as our app code. (less programming time, less cost)

I want to use the following html in my app:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera">
```

This line perfectly works on our mobile website, but in the app, it opens something that looks like a gallery.

[screenshot of the gallery wich opens in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO5Wg.png)

**Is there a way to open the camera in stead of the gallery?**

Extra info:

1. I prefer not to use the PhoneGap plugin, in that case, we need to rewrite our upload and have a complete different upload for the (mobile) website and the app, but if there is no other way, that's a great answer to.
2. I know there are similar questions, but they all don't have a good answer, or the don't use PhoneGap, or the want to use the PhoneGap API

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73162466/559079)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`

Not sure 100% if it will work, however I looked [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) for a solution and came across this.

Comment: This opens the same gallery, but with all file types (it does not recognise the image/* anymore)

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Is this of any help? https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

Comment: That is another way of uploading an image, and if the html capture is not supported in android, i can try that. But is there is a way to get it to work with the html5 capture i prefer that

Comment: I've done some googling and it doesn't look like you can do this. It just looks like it "forces" a user to select a certain type of media from their PC. Looks like you'll need to use a third party plugin for it, maybe this: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Comment: Hello, I know it is almost two years late, did you get to fix it?
Im having the same inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It's a long time ago indeed, i have never fixed this issue. I'am also not working at that company anymore.. If you can find a fix i would really love it if you post it here!