# <input accept="image/*;capture=camera"... allows any file type on mobile

Tags: html, iphone

How do I restrict image browse button to images only white allowing drop-down menu to choose from camera, library, file on mobile?

Here's what's happening:

When using `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`
I get the drop-down I need but it doesn't restrict image file type - it can be anything (*.*)

[image]

When using `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>` it's image only but there's no drop-down. Camera opens directly.

How do I get the drop-down + `image/*`?

Demo for mobile. (Mostly needed for iPhone):

```html
<p>Drop-down for camera, library, files but all files allowed:</p>
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

<p>Only images allowed but doesn't have drop-down. Opens camera directly:</p>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

*Currently, I'm using JS to restrict non-images but wanted to know if there's a html5 native way.*

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out minutes after asking

It's supposed to be a comma `,` not semi-colon `;`

```html
<p>Drop-down and Images only</p>
<input type="file" accept="capture=camera,image/*">
```

[image]

Why are most articles and tutorials using `;` is beyond me :)

Comment: This might have worked at some point on some device but for me putting it like this just opens the file browser (Chrome on Android 14). Unfortunately I couldn't find a real answer to your actual question :(

Comment: On my phone (iOS), I get that popup menu with just `accept="image/*"`, so long as I don't add the `capture` attribute. I don't think adding the `capture=camera` into the `accept` attribute makes any difference.